# Xamarin.Forms ControlTemplate Triggers

Tags: .net, wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm trying to use Triggers in my ControlTemplate but the control is not updating.  I have tried using both basic property Trigger and DataTrigger.  Has anyone used Triggers in a ControlTemplate in Xamarin based on a Parent / TemplatedParent property?  I have tried every variation of binding and Property setting I can think of.  I'm starting to think that what I'm trying to do will just not work.

Any insight appreciated.  Thanks!

```
    <Style TargetType="controls:LabeledField">
    <Setter Property="LabelForeground" Value="#888888" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="StartAndExpand" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="StartAndExpand" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,3,3,3" />
    <Setter Property="ControlTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <!--Default is "Above"-->
                    <Label x:Name="LabelText"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           FontSize="{TemplateBinding LabelFontSize}"
                           TextColor="{TemplateBinding LabelForeground}"
                           Text="{TemplateBinding Label}">
                        <Label.Triggers>
                            <Trigger TargetType="Label" Property="controls:LabeledField.LabelPosition" Value="None">
                                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger TargetType="Label" Property="controls:LabeledField.LabelPosition" Value="Right">
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Purple"/>
                                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Start" />
                                <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="{TemplateBinding LabelColumnWidth}" />
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{TemplateBinding LabelPaddingWhenRight}" />
                            </Trigger>


                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{TemplateBinding controls:LabeledField.LabelPosition}" Value="Left">
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Green"/>
                                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Start" />
                                <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="{TemplateBinding LabelColumnWidth}" />
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{TemplateBinding LabelPaddingWhenLeft}" />
                            </DataTrigger>


                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{TemplateBinding LabelPosition}" Value="Above">
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Orange"/>
                                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="End" />
                                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="-1" />
                                <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference Content}}" />
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{TemplateBinding LabelPaddingWhenAbove}" />
                            </DataTrigger>


                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{TemplateBinding Parent.LabelPosition}" Value="Below">
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Blue"/>
                                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="End" />
                                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="-1" />
                                <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference Content}}" />
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{TemplateBinding LabelPaddingWhenBelow}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Label.Triggers>
                    </Label>
```

Here is a snippet of code that defines the LabelPosition property on the LabeledField class

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty LabelPositionProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        "LabelPosition",
        typeof(LabelPosition),
        typeof(LabeledField),
        LabelPosition.Right,
        propertyChanged: UpdateLayout);

    public LabelPosition LabelPosition
    {
        get => (LabelPosition)GetValue(LabelPositionProperty);
        set => SetValue(LabelPositionProperty, LabelPosition);
    }

    public static LabelPosition GetLabelPosition(BindableObject element)
    {
        return (LabelPosition)element.GetValue(LabelColumnWidthProperty);
    }

    public static void SetLabelPosition(BindableObject element, LabelPosition value)
    {
        element.SetValue(LabelPositionProperty, value);
    }

    private static void UpdateLayout(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
    {
        var labeledField = bindable as LabeledField;
        //Calling this method will invalidate the measure and triggers a new layout cycle.
        //labeledField?.InvalidateLayout();

        //labeledField?.UpdateChildrenLayout();
        labeledField?.ForceLayout();
    }
```

Comment: I found you have  created custom `LabeledField`, but xamarin native `Label` does not has the property that you declared such as  `LabelPosition`. Could share a simple sample contain `LabeledField`?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the simplest approach does work -

```
<DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{TemplateBinding LabelPosition}" Value="Above">
       <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="End" />
       <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="-1" />
       <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference Content}}" />
       <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{TemplateBinding LabelPaddingWhenAbove}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

However, what does not work is changing the TextColor (or probably any property) in a Trigger when it is already TemplateBound.  This will not change the color -

```
<Label x:Name="LabelText"                   
       FontSize="{TemplateBinding LabelFontSize}"
       TextColor="{TemplateBinding LabelForeground}"
       Text="{TemplateBinding LabelPosition}">
       <Label.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{TemplateBinding LabelPosition}" Value="Above">
                      <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Blue"/>
             </DataTrigger>
```